# how to use a listview,without a database

Tags: c#, .net, listview, dynamic

I am totally new to .net. I am wondering how you use a listview as a dynamic tool on a web page(not an application). In the past I have used a database connection with listviews and they auto populate the listview template for you. In this case, there is no database, as the information from the form is simply getting emailed out. I was wondering how I can use a listview this way, without a database? Each listview item just has 2 fields, subject and message.

If anyone can show me an example of what I should be doing I would appreciate it. (apparently asking for a tutorial is against the rules or something? Doesn't make much sense to me)

Comment: [LIke this?](http://csharp.net-informations.com/gui/cs-listview.htm)

Comment: what does on hold mean? How am I supposed to learn if I dont ask for advice or resources, that makes absolutely no sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

Create a datatable then add these 2 columns for it as code provided below :

```
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("Subject");
  dt.Columns.Add("Message");

  DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
  dr["Subject"] = "Subject1";
  dr["Message"] = "Message1";
  dt.Rows.Add(dr);

  list.DataSource = dt;
  list.DataBind();
```

and the following code is for the design

```
        <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="list">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table id="Table1" runat="server">
                    <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
                        <th>Subject</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder"></tr>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="RssdLabel" Text='<%# Eval("Subject") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: Where would you create the datatable? I tried in pageload and I just get a blank page.

Comment: i added it in page load too and it worked fine with me,

post your design and code behind please

Comment: I had to add an empty item template,now I need it to default to the insert item template if there are no items. Im very new at this.

Comment: I am starting to understand hwo it works, but still trying to figure out how to setup CRUD for the items in the listview